# Issue with jwt-bearer on-behalf-of grant in Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

So I have an Angular app that uses the adal-angular library to authenticate with an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API. The API then uses on-behalf-of flow to authenticate with another API using the users token like this MS article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of.

The issue I have is this is working fine in the DEV environment but I have now deployed a TST environment with separate App Registrations and I am receiving the following exception when I try and request the token using on-behalf-of

> AADSTS240002: Input id_token cannot be used as 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' grant.

The code I am using to request the token

```
public async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsync(string resource)
    {
        try
        {
            string accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(AuthenticationConstants.AccessToken);

            var credentials = new ClientCredential(_azureOptions.ClientId, _azureOptions.ClientSecret);
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}")
            {
                ExtendedLifeTimeEnabled = true
            };

            // On-behalf-of auth token request call
            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                resource,
                credentials,
                new UserAssertion(accessToken));

            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (AdalServiceException asex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(asex, $"Instance: {_azureOptions.Instance} Tenant: {_azureOptions.TenantId} ClientId: {_azureOptions.ClientId}");
            throw;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And I have used Fiddler [image: Fiddler] and it looks like all the correct parameters are being passed.

Any help would be very much appreciated. I have set knownClientApplications on the second API and I have granted permissions on the Angular backend API to the second API.

Comment: Do you have separate app registrations for the Angular front-end and the back-end? Because this sounds like an error that would happen if you used one app registration for both, in which case you would be using the id token as the access token. If that is the case, you will need to make separate app registrations for the two parts.

Comment: Yeah I do use the same app registration for both as they are hosted on the same app service so have the same reply URL. It's strange it works in DEV.

Comment: Oh also @juunas I just changed "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow" from false to true in the app registration and it is now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question and the error, **it should be caused by that you angular app is not a Native(public) app**.

For using this OBO flow with this Grant type, your client must be a public client not credential client.

If you want to register your client as a WebApp/API, you can refer to [this Implementation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof):

[image]

Hope this helps!

---

Update

According to OP's comment, he/she got it working by changing `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` from `false` to `true`.

Comment: Hi @Ollie F, Is this answer helpful?

Comment: The previous Spring Boot example left me a little confused, but I see you have updated with a .NET example which I will look into. I have now got it working I just changed "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow" from false to true and the error has gone away

Comment: I'd love to see Microsoft come out with a nice up to date example solution using ASP.NET Core 2.0 (or 2.1)

Comment: Hi,@OllieF. Thanks for your sharing. I'm glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. I will update in my answer.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Hello, I still see this error even after setting "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow" to true. My App is registered as Web App. And I am used the Spring Starter Sample and Authenticate in Front-end mechanism. Error: AADSTS240002: Input id_token cannot be used as 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' grant. Could you please think of why this could be happening ??

Answer (score 3):

For me, I got it to work by changing BOTH of the following to **true**:
oauth2AllowImplicitFlow
oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) for more information.

Comment: Same here. I needed both. I had the same issue with `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` alone. Adding `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem last week with one Azure Service Registration and not another. A review found that the token didn't return an AIO being returned. It turns out that the registration had redirects with wildcards (e.g., https://*.ngrok.io) and this is incompatible with the AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf function. I'm posting this here so a future person, probably me, will find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems even when `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` and `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` were set to true. One of my Reply URLs had a wildcard in it. When the wildcard was removed, the issue was resolved.